# sockets/puma.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sockets, nginx, puma

I config my rails app with `puma` and `nginx` but while running I get the following exception:

```
*9 connect() to unix:/home/nikhil/rorworkspace/DrinkApp/shared/sockets/puma.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) 
while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /drinks HTTP/1.1", 
upstream: "http://unix:/home/nikhil/rorworkspace/DrinkApp/shared/sockets/puma.sock:/drinks", host: "localhost"
```

Comment: ... and their modes.

Comment: well after reboot it can't find a socket, anyone will answer this??

Comment: you find its solution?